# How can I get an audiobook from my PC onto my phone?

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive, audiobooks

Not sure why this is hard.  I have an audiobook, which is a folder full of MP3 files on my PC, and I want it to be on my phone local storage in a particular folder.  I have it also on Google Drive, but I see no option to do anything but download each file on at a time (on the phone app).  Surely people who listen to audiobooks all the time don't do this.  What's the easy way?

Comment: This question is pretty broad... you could use Syncthing, Warpinator, USB cable, or any of a dozen other transfer/sync utilities to sync either folders or multiple files. You would need to clarify exactly what or how (USB, network, cloud, etc) you want to sync things. Most readers should just be able to point directly to your cloud folder on Gdrive though, and you can also sync a cloud folder to your device and maintain the sync... The question is too broad to give a single "best" answer.

Comment: You could take a look at other questions using the [tag:file-transfer] tag [which have answers](/search?q=[file-transfer]+answers%3A1). But easiest is probably to simply connect the two devices with an USB cable, which should automatically pop up a file manager window on your PC to drop your files in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plug your device into a PC using USB cable, select MTP mode, and transfer your preferred data to PC. This data transfer approach is used by many Android users and is straightforward to setup.

Comment: Point taken. I've never needed to manually store anything on local phone storage until now. [Edited by Moderator Firelord]